# Module Question: Definition Basis and Free

Tags: modules, definition

I have been working with modules for some time now, but there are a two little things I have been wondering about: (1) definition of a basis (2) definition of a free module. They may seem trivial to some people, but as these definitions are quite fundamental I would like to make sure I got it right (see picture below). Thanks for your help.

[image]

Comment: Since the image only contains math, it would be nice if you actually wrote the content of it here, rather than having people open an image.

Comment: Yes, those look correct to me.

Comment: You can find some good starting points on how to format mathematics on the site [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020). [This AMS reference](ftp://ftp.ams.org/ams/doc/amsmath/short-math-guide.pdf) is very useful. If you need to format more advanced things, there are many excellent references on LaTeX on the internet, including StackExchange's own [TeX.SE](http://tex.stackexchange.com/) site.

Comment: The first looks right to me, but the second is a matter of taste.  For someone just learning about modules, that is probably the most "accessible" definition, but in my opinion "free" should be stated in terms of the universal property to emphasize the connection to other sorts of free objects.  As stated, I could call that more a "construction" of free modules than a definition.

Comment: I was just wondering, do I have to assume that the sums (in the defintion for a basis) have to be finite? I mean, do I only sum over a finite amount of elements in $I$ (i.e. $r_i=0$ for almost every $i\in I$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are the correct definitions, though there are other ways of defining "free" which are equivalent and hence also correct.  And yes, it is true that $M$ is free if and only if $M$ has a basis:

If $M$ is free then there is an isomorphism $\phi\colon\bigoplus_{i \in I}R \to M$.  Let $e_j \in \bigoplus_{i \in I}R$ be the element which has a $1$ in the $j^\text{th}$ position and zero's elsewhere.  Then you can show that $\{e_i \ | \ i \in I\}$ is a basis for $\bigoplus_{i \in I}R$ and therefore $\{\phi(e_i) \ | \ i \in I\}$ is a basis for $M$.

Conversely if $\{m_i \ | \ i \in I\}$ is a basis for $M$ then we can define $\phi\colon\bigoplus_{i \in I}R \to M$ by $(a_i) \mapsto \sum_ia_im_i$.  Then you can show that $\phi$ is an isomorphism and therefore $M$ is free.

Comment: Thanks. This helped a lot.